# AutoMapper - how do you map to property names based on class names?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

By convention, the database I'm using has its table name included in the ID e.g. the ID of an Employee table => EmployeeID.

Is it possible to use AutoMapper to wire up a convention to map {Source}.[SourceClassName]ID => {Destination}.Id and vice-versa?

By convention, I mean can I add a general rule for the profile, so that I don't have to include it in every map that is created.

I'm using AutoMapper 5.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can easily do this. There is an overload where you pass in the source type and the Destination type. For instance:

```
_config.CreateMap(SourceType, DestinationType)
```

Just get the types by name:

```
    private static Type FindType(string fullName)
{
    return
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName.Equals(fullName));
}
```